# showing columns with Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I work with tables that have lots of columns that don't fit on my screen. When I create SQL I am really looking at a few columns worth of information.

What is a better way of moving a column from the right side to the first left most column? That way my results will show the column I am interested in first.

Currently I am using

```
Select ColumnNumber201, t.*
from TableName t
```

I have a feeling this will add extra results to my query if I was concerned about counts, because it is a join. I would like avoid joins if possible.

Thanks for your help in advance.

We are using Oracle DB SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this *is* the way to display columns you're interested in - name them. In order to put them to the "front" (i.e. to be the leftmost), do exactly what you are doing.

I don't understand your concern about counts. What "join" are you talking about? There's no join in a statement you posted. This:

```
Select ColumnNumber201, t.*
from TableName t
```

selects only from one table.

Even if you join it to another table, it is the join condition and `where` clause that matters, not number of columns you select (OK, aggregates change things, but that's another story).

For example:

```
SQL> select count(*) one_column_one_table
  2  from (select e.ename
  3        from emp e);

ONE_COLUMN_ONE_TABLE
--------------------
                  14

SQL>
SQL> select count(*) many_columns_one_table
  2  from (select e.ename, e.*
  3        from emp e);

MANY_COLUMNS_ONE_TABLE
----------------------
                    14

SQL>
SQL> select count(*) many_columns_two_tables
  2  from (select d.dname, e.ename, e.*, d.*
  3        from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno);

MANY_COLUMNS_TWO_TABLES
-----------------------
                     14

SQL>
SQL> select count(*) many_columns_two_tables_where
  2  from (select d.dname, e.ename, e.*, d.*
  3        from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  4        where d.deptno = 20);

MANY_COLUMNS_TWO_TABLES_WHERE
-----------------------------
                            5

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am rusty. I ,incorrectly, thought there was an implicit join with the "t" even if the where clause wasn't included.